# how can I simplify a specific region of 3d mesh using CGAL

Tags: c++, 3d, computational-geometry, mesh, cgal

I'm using CGAL [Surface Mesh Simplification](https://doc.cgal.org/4.13.1/Surface_mesh_simplification/classEdgeCollapseSimplificationVisitor.html) to simplify 3d mesh from .off file was read as Linear_cell_complex_for_combinatorial_map and undo the edges collapsing (simplification) using  [undo_edge_collapse_surface_mesh](https://github.com/afabri/cgal/blob/SMS-undo_example-GF/Surface_mesh_simplification/examples/Surface_mesh_simplification/undo_edge_collapse_surface_mesh.cpp).

How to do the simplification and undo processes within specific selected region on the mesh.

any recommendations ,please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can constrain some edges such that they will not be removed by passing an edge --> bool map in argument.

See the named parameter is_constrained_edge_map in the [documentation of the edge_collapse() function](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Surface_mesh_simplification/group__PkgSurfaceMeshSimplificationRef.html#ga5f51d0ea2897f3c22e870279cfb4bd41) and [this CGAL example](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Surface_mesh_simplification/Surface_mesh_simplification_2edge_collapse_constrain_sharp_edges_8cpp-example.html) for an example of usage. In your case, you would just loop over the edges of your regions and constrain them.